# How to get data from a long array of data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a very array of data below called Data_Array. How do I get the 5th and 6th indexes of the data only? In an automatical approach.

```
var Data_Array = ["BETA 135 MEMB 3 6",
              "MATERIAL STEELAPPROX ALL",
              "SUPPORTS",
              "5 13 16 22 24 PINNED",
              "20 FIXED",
              "7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200",
              "9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200",
              "LOAD 1 LOADTYPE Dead  TITLE DEAD",
              "SELFWEIGHT Y -1",
              "LOAD 2 LOADTYPE Live  TITLE LIVE"]
```

I'm trying to achieve below value:

```
["7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200",
 "9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200"]
```

I'm trying to create a code in which it counts all arrays then stops whenever it detected the word FIXED. Then from there it will return its array.length then (That would be the first index). Then counts until Load (that would be the second index). So the code

```
function countIndex(array, str1, str2){

  count until Fixed then = gives 5
  count until Load then = give 7

}

Array.splice(1st_index,2nd_index);
```

I actually have code that does this but it cannot detect the strings which are not in the first index of an element. Now that the string "FIXED" is not in the first index it won't work. It only works when the str1 and str2 values are the first index of an element in an array.

```
function pullAllDataBetween(data, str1, str2) {

  var string_nodes = [];
  var append = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   if (data[i] === str1) {
      append = true;
      continue;
   } else if (data[i] === str2) {
      append = false;
      break;
   }

      if (append) {
     string_nodes.push(data[i]);
   }
  }

    return string_nodes;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(Data_Array.slice(5, 7));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[ '7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200',
  '9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200' ]
```

```js
var Data_Array = ["BETA 135 MEMB 3 6",
          "MATERIAL STEELAPPROX ALL",
          "SUPPORTS",
          "5 13 16 22 24 PINNED",
          "20 FIXED",
          "7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200",
          "9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200",
          "LOAD 1 LOADTYPE Dead  TITLE DEAD",
          "SELFWEIGHT Y -1",
          "LOAD 2 LOADTYPE Live  TITLE LIVE"];

console.log(Data_Array.slice(5, 7));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

To get the array of only those strings which contains `the word FIXED` and to get it's length:

```js
var Data_Array = ["BETA 135 MEMB 3 6",
          "MATERIAL STEELAPPROX ALL",
          "SUPPORTS",
          "5 13 16 22 24 PINNED",
          "20 FIXED",
          "7 FIXED BUT FX KFY 200",
          "9 FIXED BUT FZ MX KFY 150 KMZ 200",
          "LOAD 1 LOADTYPE Dead  TITLE DEAD",
          "SELFWEIGHT Y -1",
          "LOAD 2 LOADTYPE Live  TITLE LIVE"];


var arr = Data_Array.filter(line => /FIXED/.test(line));

console.log(arr);

console.log(arr.length);

function count(arr, str){
  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i].indexOf(str)!==-1)
      return i;
  }
}

console.log(count(Data_Array, "FIXED"));

console.log(count(Data_Array, "LOAD"));
```

Comment: how do i count the 5th index in an automatic approach?

Comment: What do you mean by counting?

Comment: wait i will rephrase my question

Comment: i added my code but it doesn't work since the string i'm trying to detect is not in the first index of the elemnt of an array. It can only detect the first string of the first index of an element.

Comment: why does it returns 3 not 4? on FIXED then i tried LOAD it returns 2 instead of 7?

Comment: Because there are three strings in the array having FIXED in them. Why were you expecting `4`?

Comment: I think this code counts the existence of the strings not counting the length of where they existed?

Comment: I mean it should count from 0 index until it finds the string FIXED so it would be 5 and 7. I'm not asking for their existence i'm asking for counting until it reach the value then recount for the second index LOAD. so the answer would be like 5 and 7 index

Comment: From there i could use their value and use your splice code. Cause in reality this data could become even longer. So i want to automate the index value.

Comment: The first FIXED is at 4, and first LOAD is at 7. Arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: Added a function `count()` which returns the index of the first occurrence of a string.

Comment: yeah how do i automate the count of their indexes so i won't have to put the number of indexes of where there are manually?

Comment: I have added it in my answer. Check.